# How to read a pdf file from left to right position without scrolling up & down in android emulator(pdf viewer)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I created a pdf viewer for android, in that the pdf files are open in scrolling position(up and down) but i need it in left to right position. I tried it in various combos but it's failed to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 /**
         * Handle touch event coming from Android system.
         */
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            this.lastControlsUseMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.v(TAG, ""+event.getAction());
            if (!gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                Log.v(TAG, ""+event.getAction());
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.e(TAG, " - DOWN -");
                        Log.e(TAG, " getX: " + event.getX());
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                    lastX = downX;
                    lastY = downY;
                    lockedVertically = verticalScrollLock;
                    maxExcursionY = 0;
                    scroller = null;


                }
                else if

                    (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Log.e(TAG, " - UP -");
                    Log.e(TAG, " getY: " + event.getY());

                }

                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    if (lockedVertically && unlocksVerticalLock(event)) 
                        lockedVertically = false;

                    float dx = event.getX() - lastX;
                    float dy = event.getY() - lastY;

                    float excursionY = Math.abs(event.getY() - downY);

                    if (excursionY > maxExcursionY)
                        maxExcursionY = excursionY;

                    if (lockedVertically)
                        dx = 0;

                    doScroll((int)-dx, (int)-dy);

                    lastX = event.getX();
                    lastY = event.getY();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I neaded Horizontal Scrolling with paging once and came across [this,](http://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=62)

With this class you can add views in code and swipe through them.

Hope this helps